# Excel VBA increasing rows/columns

Tags: vba, excel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNJTd.jpg

In my image I have my form which upon entering information into the text boxes and pressing enter will place the information into the correct places below the titles, what i'm wanting to do is either have a next button that will go down one row and a back button that will go up one row and allows me to enter information into a 'database' per say or i would like to have it automatically jump down one row upon clicking 'Enter'. I have looked and I can't find anything that is quite what i'm asking and response is great, thanks.

This is what i have so far.

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`
`Dim x As Integer`
`x = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1`
`Cells(x, 1) = TextBox1.Value`
`Cells(x, 2) = TextBox2.Value`
`Cells(x, 3) = TextBox3.Value`
`Cells(x, 4) = TextBox4.Value`
`Cells(x, 5) = TextBox5.Value`
`End Sub`

Comment: `can't find anything that is quite what i'm asking` why can't you modify it?

Comment: I didn't quite word it right sorry,I mean I didn't find any that would work with what I have to do on my spreadsheet, I looked/tried to see if I could modify them with what  have but i'm new to VBA so i haven't come up with anything successful.

Comment: Post what you have so we can see what's wrong. That's the point of SO XD

Comment: I updated my original post thanks as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `x=2` with finding the next empty row

```
If Cells(2,1) = "" Then
    x = 2
Else
    x = Cells(1,1).End(xlDown).Row + 1
End If
```

Comment: i added it in like so:
"Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x As Integer
x = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1
Cells(x, 1) = TextBox1.Value
Cells(x, 2) = TextBox2.Value
Cells(x, 3) = TextBox3.Value
Cells(x, 4) = TextBox4.Value
Cells(x, 5) = TextBox5.Value
End Sub"
but i keep getting a runtime error '6': Overflow
i'm new to VBA so sorry if it's a stupid question to you

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a check if the 2nd row is empty and do the code only if it is not.  Otherwise, when 2nd row is empty this will got down to last possible row (1M).  See updated code.